# Updating child elements of data joins in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, updates

I'm having trouble grasping a basic operation in d3: updating child elements for a changing data set.
The child element needs to be "appended" for the first pass, and modified for subsequent passes. For the parent element that can be controlled using the "enter" operation, but I can't see how to use it for the children. I am using the bubble layout, but I don't think that is the issue.

```
var node = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(
bubble.nodes(classes(json)).filter(function (d) {
    return !d.children;
}), function (d) {
    return d.className;
});

node.select("circle").attr("r", function (d) {
    return d.r;
});

node.enter().append("g").attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
});

node.append("circle").attr("r", function (d) {
    return d.r;
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/johnpoole/xsafy/131/ with the code running.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. The group you're appending to the "parent" doesn't seem to be used for anything and the circles don't seem to be selected when updating. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to create a bubble layout and change the radius of the circles during the update. The circle/child is appended to a node/parent to display the circle and it's radius. Not selecting the circles during the update ,(with a reference to the new radius) is the problem.

Comment: Why are you adding `g` elements? Just adding the circles should be sufficient.

Comment: I copied some of the code from a Mike Bostock example which used g elements: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

Comment: I would recommend starting with a simple example. In particular if you're not that familiar with d3 yet, the tutorials are a much better starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer eventually came to me. It's just a matter of doing the original "appends" on the result of the enter()

```
var node = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(
    bubble.nodes(classes(json)).filter(function(d) {
        return !d.children;
    }), function(d) {
        return d.className;
    });

node.select("circle").attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.r;
    }).style("fill", function(d) {
        return fill(d.r);
    });
    
node.enter().append("g").attr("class", "node")
.attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.x + ","+ d.y +     ")";
}).append("circle").attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.r;
}).style("fill", function(d) {
        return fill(d.className);
});
```